# Firebase does not provide proof of the notifications been sent or delivered to the android app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-notifications

When testing to the android app from the firebase console the status of the messages says completed and shows the delivery date. How do we check whether a message has sent to the receipts and delivered in an android app with fire-base: https://console.firebase.google.com?

I am working on a firebase quickstart app to test push notification message to my target users. Please help me.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for here - do you want the exact time an individual user received a message? You could log this in your FirebaseMessagingService for each user, and send this up to your server or DB, but this sounds like it will be complex. Also, notifications sent from the console are limited in that they will not be received unless your app is in the foreground when they are received. On the other hand, you could use an http client like postman to send "data" notifications, which are received in the background and then you could log this receipt date

Answer (score 0):

@SaikCaskey have an insight of the solution of your question, though I do not agree on some points.

The push notification is not guaranteed to be received to your targeted user actually. Push notification might fail for several reason. But that's not the issue here. You might get notifications even if your application is in background or stopped. You need to start your `FirebaseMessagingService` with `START_STICKY`. This behaviour might differ in different devices too. Some devices allows/disallow this behaviour of receiving push notification when your app is stopped.

So, if you need to log when your user has received the push notification, you might get it in a bit complex way. When your device will come online you'll get the push and in your `onMessageReceived` function you can get the `System.Clock` for getting the time of notification received. Then create an instance of Firebase and then set the time to the reference node of the user's notification delivery time.

Hope that helps!